# Mockito 3.1 VerificationWithTimeout.never Alternative

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would to use Mockito to verify that a method `onMethodCall` was never called on a stub `listener`.On previous versions of Mockito, I am able to use the `VerificationWithTimeout.never()` method as follows:

`verify(listener, timeout(100).never()).onMethodCall()`

However this method seems to be removed in Mockito 3.1. How can I achieve this in mockito 3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that the correct method to use is `after(100).never()`.

There is a message from Mockito explaining the removal of the timeout().never() method.

````
timeout() should not be used with atMost() or never() because...
...it does not make much sense - the test would have passed immediately in concurrency
We kept this method only to avoid compilation errors when upgrading Mockito.
In future release we will remove timeout(x).atMost(y) from the API.
If you want to find out more please refer to issue 235```
````